# Computer network addressing (Subnet Masks)

Tags: networking

I am trying to understand that Why 255.255.255.0 regarded as class B subnet mask,while many students in my class argue that the mask address is of class C.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading one of the relevant RFCs. [RFC 870](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc870), for instance.
Here is an excerpt from that memo:

```
      The third type of address, class C, has a 21-bit network number
      and a 8-bit local address.  The three highest-order bits are set
      to 1-1-0.  This allows 2,097,152 class C networks.

                           1                   2                   3
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |1 1 0|                    NETWORK              | Local Address |
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

                             Class C Address
```

In it, class C networks are defined to have 8-bit local address, hence the mask `255.255.255.0`.